# Regarding high resolution pdf imagemagick

Tags: image-processing, pdf-generation, imagemagick-convert, magickwand

I am using magickwand for php, to convert html to pdf which includes lots of images. I need to have high quality resolution pdf for offset printing. My issue is, while conversion from html to pdf, quality of images reduced by 30% and taking lot of conversion time. I would like to know, is there any way to improve image quality and speed up time for image conversion. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing either your images or your code! You could try setting the resolution to something higher before you read the HTML in say something like `144` or `288` and see how that affects the time and generated file size and quality. You could also maybe try `wkhtmltopdf`.

Comment: Thank you for the response...will try the same....